# Im trying to combine date times and string in the same column of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of names like this:

`['Albert Einstein', 'Benjamin Franklin', 'J. Edgar Hoover',....]`

And a list of date-times:

`[datetime.date(1642, 12, 25), datetime.date(1879, 3, 14), datetime.date(1706, 1, 17),.....]`

now I'm trying to add them together in between of each other like this in a new list:

`[('Albert Einstein', datetime.date(1879, 3, 14)),...`

Nothing I tried seem to work. It also doesn't seem possible to me with append or extend, hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did you try with `zip` ?

Comment: @CeliusStingher no how would that work?

Comment: You can see my answer where I provide an example with the values you give and the output

Comment: seems a bit different to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
names = ['Albert Einstein', 'Benjamin Franklin', 'J. Edgar Hoover']
dates = [datetime.date(1642, 12, 25), datetime.date(1879, 3, 14), datetime.date(1706, 1, 17)]

print(list(zip(names, dates)))
```

**Output:**

```
[('Albert Einstein', datetime.date(1642, 12, 25)), ('Benjamin Franklin', datetime.date(1879, 3, 14)), ('J. Edgar Hoover', datetime.date(1706, 1, 17))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use zip(a, b) for the two lists, e.g.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(list(zip(a, b)))

[(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
```

Comment: I believe this would print a zip object, not a list with the tuple.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the mistake

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can simply use `zip` which can take lists as parameters and returns an iterator, with tuples of i-th position of the lists passed as arguments, therefore if we try to print it, we'll get a `zip object at ...` that's why we need to use `list()` so we can access the values in a list format:

```
import datetime
people = ['Albert Einstein', 'Benjamin Franklin', 'J. Edgar Hoover']
dates = [datetime.date(1642, 12, 25), datetime.date(1879, 3, 14), datetime.date(1706, 1, 17)]
output = list(zip(people,dates))
```

For example:

```
[('Albert Einstein', datetime.date(1642, 12, 25)),
 ('Benjamin Franklin', datetime.date(1879, 3, 14)),
 ('J. Edgar Hoover', datetime.date(1706, 1, 17))]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. So what if I want the zip to be a list or doesn't that matter?

Comment: Because `zip` returns an iterator, if you wish to use it at list, then you must use `list()` with the `zip object`. Of course you can choose not to.